# Copy specific folders on Windows (robocopy)

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I want to do some thing simple (I thought...)

I've got something like this:

```
Folder01 
  |_File1
  |_File2
  |_File3
Folder02
  |_File1
  |_File2
  |_File3
Folder03
  |_File1
  |_File2
  |_File3
Folder04
  |_File1
  |_File2
  |_File3
```

I just want to copy these Data with robocopy to a target (because I need a logfile and have to specify with attributes to copy).

But due to some limitations I can not copy the data in one run and have to split this Job (in real about 5000 Folders, 3TB).

So I want to specify the "starting folder" and the last folder like Folder00X (Folder001, +1, Folder100 ; the Job should start with Folder001 and with steps +1 it should copy the Folder002, Folder003....Folder100).

Answer (score 0):

#### The job should start with Folder001, step +1, copy Folder002, ... Folder100

You can use a `for /l` loop in a batch file to do this.

The following batch file echoes the required list of folder names:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do (
   rem prefix the count with leading zeros
   set "_number=00%%i"
   rem extract the last 3 digits
   echo Folder!_number:~-3!
   )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The batch file should be located in the directory one level above `Folder001`
- Replace the `echo` command with a `robocopy` command that does the copy for you.
- To process names with `4` digits (for example Folder1000, ... Folder 2000) you need to change the batch file.

  - Replace `(1,1,100)` with `(1000,1,2000)`
  - Replace `"_number=00%%i"` with `"_number=000%%i"`
  - Replace `Folder!_number:~-3!` with `Folder!_number:~-4!`

---

#### Syntax

> ```
> FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command
> ```
>
> **Key**
>
> - start       : The first number
> - step        : The amount by which to increment the sequence
> - end         : The last number

Source - [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).